# Location of shower drain

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

My GC wants to install shower drain in corner of the shower pan. Is that a good idea? We can't put it in the middle because of the drain pipe being in the way.

[image]

Comment: Sure, but you don't get to wonder why your white grout is always turning moldy black in that corner.

Comment: I've seen edge drains installed. They're kinda like the curb on the street - the drain runs all along one edge or for several inches straight along the edge instead of being round. It can almost disappear into the curb at the edge of the shower pan. Of course, it takes a special drain design to do it, but if you're in a bind, it may be time to get creative and have it look special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing structurally wrong with putting the drain in the corner. the floor will slope to the drain, the water will flow down the slope to the drain.

The drain won't be underfoot, this is actually an advantage.

It can make getting the tileing to look good challenging because there will be slopes against at-least two walls.

if you can picture this in your mind and don't like the picture, a slit drain may be another option.

Comment: Is there a better location for it?

Comment: Probably not,  I meant challenging, it's certainly not impossible to make it look good, just care needs to be taken. a slit drain may be another option.